# haskell minimax / nested conditions and wheres

Tags: haskell, nested, minimax

For an assignment I need to write a Minimax function on a Gametree provided to the function (as a tree of boards; Rose Board) and a player who's turn it is. However I'm getting this error about parse error on input '|'. Probably because I nested conditions and where statements but I'm not sure if I done this properly or if this is even possible (or should be done in a different way):

```
minimax :: Player -> Rose Board -> Rose Int --Rose Int = Int :> [Rose Ints]
minimax p rb = minimax' rb p
          where minimax' (b :> [rbs]) p0 | null rbs  = result
                                                where result | p0 == p   =  1
                                                             | otherwise = -1
                                         | otherwise = 0 :> (minimax' rbs (nextPlayer p0))
```

If someone could help me out it's much appreciated!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

Comment: You have to move the inner `where` after the guards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to fix this is probably to use `let` instead of `where`:

```
minimax :: Player -> Rose Board -> Rose Int --Rose Int = Int :> [Rose Ints]
minimax p rb = minimax' rb p
          where minimax' (b :> [rbs]) p0 | null rbs  = let result | p0 == p   =  1
                                                                  | otherwise = -1
                                                       in result
                                         | otherwise = 0 :> (minimax' rbs (nextPlayer p0))
```

but you could also just use a conditional expression:

```
minimax :: Player -> Rose Board -> Rose Int --Rose Int = Int :> [Rose Ints]
minimax p rb = minimax' rb p
          where minimax' (b :> [rbs]) p0 | null rbs  = if p0 == p then 1 else -1
                                         | otherwise = 0 :> (minimax' rbs (nextPlayer p0))
```